# NLP - How to get the a list of frequently asked questions on a list of questions

Tags: python, machine-learning, deep-learning, nlp, data-science

Everything is in the title, so basically I have a list of several questions as strings and the idea is to get another list of frequently asked questions within that first list of questions.

I don't know if it'll make sense but I'll try to explain the approach I tried.

The approach consist of calculating the cosine similarity of each element of the list with the rest of the elements not including the element being processed to prevent performing calculations with the same element.

That said, a dictionary will be created containing the keys as the index of each element being processed, while the values will be a list of indexes of each element which has a cosine similarity above the threshold with the index of the key.

Once the dictionary has been created, the keys' indexes with the highest length of list on their values will be considered as being frequent questions, after that you can pick up the top 10 or any number you'd like.

Firstly, a downside is that it takes a lot of time to execute knowing that I've +60k questions (14 days).
Secondly, I don't know if it's the best way to solve this problem, what do you think?
Finally, if you have a more clearer and better idea to solve the problem, I'm all ears, it can also help other people with the same problem.

```
import nltk
from nltk.corpus import stopwords
from nltk.tokenize import word_tokenize
nltk.download('punkt')
nltk.download('stopwords')

list_of_questions = ['How does umap know which high dimensional datapoint belongs to which cluster?',...]

score = dict()
threshold = 0.7
#tokenization

#sw contains the list of stopwords
sw = stopwords.words('english')

for index, main_question in enumerate(list_of_questions):
    similarities = []
    temp_list = list_of_questions.copy()
    X_list = word_tokenize(main_question)
    temp_list.pop(index)
    for question_ in temp_list:
        l1 =[];l2 =[]
        Y_list = word_tokenize(question_)
        
        if len(X_list) == 0 or len(Y_list) == 0:
            continue
        #remove stop words from the string
        X_set = {w for w in X_list if not w in sw} 
        Y_set = {w for w in Y_list if not w in sw}

        #form a set containing keywords of both strings 
        rvector = X_set.union(Y_set) 
        for w in rvector:
            if w in X_set: l1.append(1) # create a vector
            else: l1.append(0)
            if w in Y_set: l2.append(1)
            else: l2.append(0)
        c = 0

        #cosine formula 
        try:
            for i in range(len(rvector)):
                    c+= l1[i]*l2[i]
            cosine = c / float((sum(l1)*sum(l2))**0.5)
            if cosine > threshold:
                similarities.append(list_of_questions.index(question_))
                print("Cosine similarity: ", cosine)
        except:
            continue
    score[index] = similarities
```

Comment: Finding the most similar questions usually requires computing similarity between all the pairs. In case the data is fixed, this can be precomputed. If not, there are [techniques to make this more efficient](https://datascience.stackexchange.com/a/54582/64377) but it's more complex.

Comment: @Erwan The method you mentioned can indeed work, but knowing the data is fixed, I've been suggested to run the same code in a much faster language such as C or Rust. Thanks for you answer.

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest the following:

- Create an n*n similarity matrix, where n is the number of questions in the list.
- After calculating the similarity matrix, you can run an unsupervised clustering algorithm to cluster similar/related questions together. I would suggest the **[Chinese Whispers](https://github.com/nlpub/chinese-whispers-python)** clustering algorithm.

Regarding the similarity between the questions, there are more efficient ways to capture the similarity, check out this library https://pypi.org/project/textdistance/ . or you can use SpaCy for this purpose https://betterprogramming.pub/the-beginners-guide-to-similarity-matching-using-spacy-782fc2922f7c

Comment: Thanks for your answer. The textdistance appear to be interesting, especially having a variety of algorithms to benchmark and select the perfect one. Definitely gonna give it a try.